# Is there a mode for viewing keystroke lossage in realtime?

Tags: keystrokes, pairing

`C-h l` shows the lossage help buffer, which shows recent keystrokes. Pressing `g` appears to revert it, causing it to update. Unfortunately, enabling `auto-revert-mode` does not change it to update continuously.

It would be nice if I could open up another window or frame and just display lossage in real time to show viewers what I am typing. This could also be used for pairing in a tmux/tmate session. Some of the videos online have something like this, but they appear to be external applications and OS specific.

Is there a nice way to show keystrokes in real time as they occur from within Emacs?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Addressing the last question in your post: you can get an auto-updating log of commands & key strokes by using https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode which is also available on MELPA - by default it only shows non-trivial commands (so no self-insert or cursor movement commands). It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Yes. There's a package called `mwe-log-commands`, which is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/overtone/live-coding-emacs/blob/master/lib/mwe-log-commands.el).

Just run `M-x mwe:log-keyboard-commands` to start recording, then `M-x mwe:open-command-log-buffer` will open a buffer which shows the typed commands in real time.

[command-log-mode](https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode) is a newer and more actively-maintained fork of `mwe-log-commands`, so it might be preferable these days.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a
[post-command-hook](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/post-command-hook)
to update the lossage buffer. The following snippet does that for you
(on a buffer local basis), but it assumes you've renamed the lossage
buffer to "Lossage" (so this way you can still open other help
buffers).

```
(defun update-lossage-buffer ()
  "Update the \"Lossage\" buffer.
For this to work, visit the lossage buffer, and call
M-x rename-buffer Lossage RET"
  (save-excursion
    (let ((b (get-buffer "Lossage")))
      (when (buffer-live-p b)
        (with-current-buffer b
          (revert-buffer nil 'noconfirm))))))
(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'update-lossage-buffer nil 'local)
```

Answer (score 3):

The lossage help buffer is not associated with a file on disk. Hence auto revert mode does not work. A pseudo realtime alternative can be using
 `(open-dribble-file "FILE")` which writes all keystrokes to FILE. Using `auto-revert-tail-mode` on FILE buffer can reflect the keystrokes.

Another way would be to advice `self-insert-command`(and some prefix keys) to echo to a buffer.